# SharePoint Field with Guid type always has null value

Tags: list, development, column, event-handlers, guid

I have a custom page library with Guid type field in my SP2013 portal.  ItemAdded event receiver set value to this field. But when I try to get value from this field by update receiver I get always null value although in DispForm it has normal guid value.

Is it specific behaviour of Guid type field or I made somewhere mistakes in receivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this behaviour many times and concluded: it is need elevated privileges for access to this type field.